# What is the purpose of meta http-equiv attributes with non-standard values?

Tags: html, meta-tags, http-equiv

I'm assuming this is some (presumably old-fashioned) SEO technique, but I can't find any information on it. Why would someone have the following in the `<head>` of their website?

```
<meta http-equiv="web design" content="internet design"/>
<meta http-equiv="internet design" content="interactive design"/>
<meta http-equiv="interactive design" content="flash design"/>
<meta http-equiv="flash design" content="html design"/>
<meta http-equiv="html design" content="website design"/>
<meta http-equiv="website design" content="web design"/>
```

Comment: thinking it is someone that had no clue.

Comment: Just to add some context - there is a very old-fashioned website in my area selling web design services which still, to this day, ranks extremely highly in Google despite high quality opposition - I'm curious as to why.

Comment: A `meta`  element with `http-equiv` [`defines the pragma that can alter servers and user-agents behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv). You should use a name that exists as header in the HTTP Protocol. All of the above are not valid, so they don't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unnless you set your http server to accept those fancy words as http headers, no, they are useless.

Description of that `meta` tag:

> HTTP servers use this attribute to gather information for HTTP
>   response message headers.

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-http-equiv